# Is it possible to grab the @XmlElement name value instead of the variable name for a Object to Json convertion?

Tags: json, gson

So I have this code:

```
<xs:element name="Headers">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Headers Object</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>               
            <xs:element name="content-type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
             </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I create the class Headers, I get this for the content-type element:

```
 @XmlElement(name = "content-type")
 protected String contentType;
```

I'm using Gson to convert the object to json:

```
"headers": [{           
    "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 }],
```

What I need is to get the contentType element as I had it in the xsd file, so my question is if there is any chance to grab the @XmlElement name value and use that in the convertion instead of the variable name. I tried xstream library also but get the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@SerializedName("content-type")`

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.
And for this one don't need to modify the xsd to add @SerializedName("content-type") which is not also time taking if xsd is very large.

**PS:** I am using Gson API for this.

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.setFieldNamingStrategy(new CustomFieldNamePolicy());
```

And the CustomFieldNamePolicy class can be defined as :

```
public class CustomFieldNamePolicy implements FieldNamingStrategy{

    @Override
    public String translateName(Field paramField) {

        Annotation annotationName = null;

        if(null != (annotationName = paramField.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class))){
            return ((XmlElement) annotationName).name();
        }else if(null != (annotationName = paramField.getAnnotation(XmlAttribute.class))){
            return ((XmlAttribute)annotationName).name();
        }
        return paramField.getName();
    }
}
```